# Grunt compiling SASS differently on another machine

Tags: sass, gruntjs, bourbon, neat

I have been working on a project on a Mac Mini in our office, but when I have pulled the GIT repo and started working on my Macbook Pro at home the SASS isn't compiling the same CSS. The exact same node modules are being used, and it displays no errors when compiling.

Specifically, it's generating different output using Bourbon Neat's display table functionality : different widths are specified and in fact the table display doesn't work at all (I can't quite figure out why yet though).

There may be other differences too, but I haven't found any yet. What could possibly be causing this problem?

Comment: What version of bourbon and neat do you have in both machines?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with a coworkers machine.

I found out that although the listed packages in our main package.json had the same major version, the dependent packages of our packages (those are stored in /node_modules) had a different minor version.

I was able to force the same versions by removing "~" for versions of dependencies and only accepting the exact same version.